# getting no such file or directory error in phpExcel class when running example

Tags: php, phpexcel

I just recently downloaded phpExcel library package and I followed the installation file.
I checked all the requirements to run the phpExcel classes.

To check if the library was working I ran `01simplephar.php` from the *Example* folder in the phpExcel directory.

But I get this error :

> require_once(../Build/PHPExcel.phar): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Xampp\htdocs\Excel\Examples\01pharSimple.php on line 42

I have  already checked that the extensions are active.
It seems that they are running but it still does not execute.

Comment: Where did you download the phar file from?

Comment: it came with the Excel library

Comment: From codeplex? From github? Downloaded via composer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. 
Go into the php file : 01simplephar.php

change line :

```
require_once '../Build/PHPExcel.phar';
```

to:

```
require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel.php';
```

That should fix your problem. You're handling the zip file not the repo...so you wouldn't have the build folder.